# How to mount an NTFS partition writable for a non-root user?

Tags: linux, debian, mount, ntfs, ntfs-3g

I am using Debian 8.8 and am using ntfs-3g to mount an NTFS partition in `/etc/fstab`. Here is my entry:

```
/dev/sdc1  /mnt/data_backup  ntfs-3g  rw,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0002,fmask=0003  0  0
```

It is fine for my account `userA` to read and write the partition. However, my workstation is open to another `userB` which is not in the `root` group. Is there any way to make the partition writable for the non-root `userB`? And the best result will be that `userB` can only append but cannot remove the files in the partition. An FTP solution is also acceptable. Thanks!

Comment: is that means userB has no permission to access /mnt/data_backup, what if you add this 'permission'? and modify option uid, gid should be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I spent some time learning the concept of users and groups, which help me to understand the mechanism of [ntfs-3g](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NTFS-3G#Linux_compatible_permissions) module. Here is my solution:

1. Create a group `ntfs`, and add the `userA` and `userB` to the group.
2. Modify gid in `/etc/fstab` to `gid=ntfs`. Then the mask means all users in the group can write the partition.

@Seven Thanks!

Comment: just use the NTFS3 kernel driver and mount with the acl option to enable POSIX permissions

Answer (score 0):

**Asked 4 years, 10 months ago**

currently 2022-05-11

I use RHEL/CentOS 7.9, and using `ntfs-3g-2021.8.22-2.el7.x86_64.rpm` and `ntfs-3g-libs-2021.8.22-2.el7.x86_64.rpm` which I believe come from the EPEL repository, I have no problems with mounting an ntfs partition as writable.  In fact using this latest ntfs-3g I do not even have to use the `-t ntfs-3g` option for the mount command.  My ntfs file systems however do have `rwxrwxrwx` for everything on them when being mounted in linux.

Back when I was using ntfs-3g, like 2019 version, it did work but I had to use the `-t ntfs-3g` option when mounting, among other nuances.

So the current answer to this question, based on my experience and I use a usb portable disk formatted as ntfs under windows 10 to transfer data between my windows pc to linux servers... all the time for the last couple years... I have no problems mounting an ntfs partition in linux, and being able to write to it regardless of the linux user.  So use the latest ntfs-3g version.

But if you want to ntfs-3g mount an ntfs partition and have a reasonable user/group permission policy that is a different story.

Comment: the NTFS kernel driver has been available since 2021. There's no reason to use the much worse NTFS-3g FUSE driver

Comment: what are you implying?  As of now with RHEL 8.8 if you do not manually install `ntfs-3g` and `ntfs-3g-libs` which show as version `2022.10.3-1` you cannot mount NTFS.  **What other way is there to do this?**  whether it's a *kernel driver* or a *FUSE driver* whatever that means... which as a user as long as it works reliably I don't care which it is; I've **never** had a problem doing what i've been doing and i'm not aware of any other way